# How to move installed software in New Kernel Version from old kernel?

Tags: software-installation, kernel, updates

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I cannot find my software from the older kernel version to the newer one. For example, I installed Sublime text editor in the last version but in the newer version, it's not installed.
Am I doing anything wrong or this is the way kernels are meant to behave?
(Yes I know sticking to the previous version could be the easy escape.)

Updated kernel:5.13.0-28-generic.

Comment: Text editors are user level programs, newer kernels only involve newer kernel modules (ie. what are commonly called *drivers*) thus changing a kernel may result in newer *drivers* being used, but no user-level changes occur.  You're describing an event that cannot be the cause of a user-level change; so you're missing the real problem or cause.  It may help us to understand if you're specific as to your issue.  FYI:  The kernel is the *core* of the OS & deals with the hardware itself; so graphics drivers (*a kernel module*) may change but not commands, or GUI apps are user level & don't change

Comment: The software should be available irrespective of which kernel you boot. Please clarify the problem.

Comment: Hoe did you update from the old kernel to the new one ?

Comment: I would guess Sublime was "installed" by some other means than dpkg / apt; thus leaving it vulnerable to changes done by the system installer.

Comment: Yes, @Hannu you are right. I have installed it using the executable script after downloading it from the web. Are you indicating that a newer kernel would maintain those user-level apps which are maintained by pkg-managers?

Comment: @SorenA I updated using the default GUI-based update manager.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi The problem is every time boot up the updated kernel version I miss my installed applications while if I load the previously installed version from Grub applications are there.

Comment: The installation method (often) plays a major role; install **all** software using dpkg / apt / apt-get  and you are a lot safer than when mixing methods. These three uses the same "tracking" so allows for a controlled uninstall / reinstall / check.  See e.g. `apt-get --help`

Comment: @Hannu Ok but what about the current state? Do I have to install all softwares which are not maintained by pkg-manager again manually?